# C++ struct functor as function template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, struct, cuda

I am confused, I know that CUDA and other libraries allow the usage of a template struct as the functor. Thus I have designed a few of them for a neural network class:

```
struct sigmoid
{
     sigmoid()=default;                                                           
     __device__ float operator()(const float x) const                                                                                     
    {                                                                                                                                     
         float exp_val = __expf(-x);                                                                                                       
         float denom = __fadd_rz(1.f,exp_val);                                                                                             
         return __fdividef(1.f,denom);                                                
    }                                                                     
};
```

When I use this for a CUDA kernel, its usage is somewhat straightforward:

```
activate<sigmoid><<num_blocks_x,block_threads_x>>>(sigmoid(),output_ptr);
```

For:

```
template <typename F>                                                                                                                     
__global__ void activate(F const& func, float * input)                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                         
   int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;                                                                                        
   input[x]  = func(input[x]);                                                                                                           
}
```

However I want to wrap the function template **around** the method that calls the CUDA kernel, and then forward it to it:

```
template <class A>                                                                                                             
thrust::host_vector<float> propagate (                                                                                                
                                       A func,                                                                 
                                       thrust::device_vector<float> & input                                                          
                                     ) const;
```

I've implemented it into a separate header, which is being included at the end of the header which declares the class.

```
class ann
{
...
};
#include ann_imp.hpp
```

And the imp header:

```
template <class A> inline                                                                                                                   
__host__ thrust::host_vector<float> ann::propagate (                                                                                        
                                                       A func,                                                                            
                                                       thrust::device_vector<float> & input                                               
                                                    ) const                                                                                 
{
     activate<func><<<num_blocks_x,block_threads_x>>>(func(),output_ptr);
}
```

Yet when I call the actual `propagate` method I run into trouble:

```
net.propagate<sigmoid>( sigmoid(), in_vec1 );
```

Produces:

```
error: function "sigmoid::operator()" cannot be called with the given argument list
            object type is: sigmoid
```

When I don't use the `operator()` but only the typename:

```
xor_net.propagate<sigmoid>( sigmoid, in_vec1 );
```

I get:

```
error: type name is not allowed
```

Using an actual object yields the same error:

```
sigmoid func;
xor_net.propagate<sigmoid>( func, in_vec1 );
```

I've tried playing around with the parameter being `A const& func` and such, but to no avail.

How do I pass a struct functor, and then forward it to the CUDA kernel?

**EDIT**
Without the wrapper, calling the activation function simply required:

```
activate<sigmoid><<<num_blocks_x,block_threads_x>>>(sigmoid(),output_ptr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
 __device__ float operator()(const float x) const ...
```

The function needs an argument of type `float`. You are calling it from `ann::propagate` as:

```
activate<func><<<num_blocks_x,block_threads_x>>>(func(),output_ptr);
                                                 ^^^^^^
```

I believe that line needs to be:

```
activate<A><<<num_blocks_x,block_threads_x>>>(func,output_ptr);
       ^^^^                                   ^^^^^     
       Fix the type                           Use the object.
```

Comment: This worked! Now I'm even more confused. Why was I getting an error when calling `propagate` and not when calling `activate` ???
When I didn't use the wrapper, I had to call it: `activate<sigmoid><<<...,...>>>( sigmoid(), ptr );`

Comment: @Alex, I don't know how to answer that without seeing the full error stack.

Comment: @R Sahu I made an edit. When I didn't use any template wrappers, and only (directly) called the `activate` all I had to do was call the `sigmoid()` as the cuda kernel param, and use the typename. Why does the wrapper get the error, and not the cuda kernel call?

Comment: @Alex, in the direct call to `activate`, you are using `sigmoid` as the template parameter and using a newly constructed object as the argument. When `ann::propagate`, is called you are using the same pattern. By the time you are inside `ann::propagate`, `func` is an instance of `sigmoid` (or `A`, if you will).

Comment: Thanks that is what I eventually thought was going on.
So can't I instantiate in the `propagate` call a new object inline rather than doing it beforehand?

Comment: @Alex, of course you can. In that case, you can either (a) not pass an object to `propagate` and construct a new object in the call to `activate` using `A()` or (b) construct a new object from the passed object and use the new object with `A(func)` in the call to `activate`.